# Store serialized arrays or individual columns?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm in need of advice. I have a large table that a user will fill out (roughly 150+ fields), many of which are (bool) check boxes, and a few text inputs. I know that if I store the tables as serialized arrays, it would dramatically affect searching and exporting the database into another usable format (like a .csv).

Would I be better off storing each field individually and creating a massive table, store it serialized anyway, or is there some other way to achieve this with a happy middle?

Comment: The answer greatly depends on what those bools represent and how you expect to use/search them in the data. _You could use a "child" table where each row references the parent and has a value "name" and value "value" for each bool; but I usually recommend against this (anti)pattern._

Comment: With that many fields, you might also want to consider several tables with a 1:1 relationship with "main" table; so still one "row"  in a sense but broken up into related chunks across tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum amount of column in a mysql database is around 4000 : [see reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/column-count-limit.html). You only want to use two hundred, which is not a lot.

I think you're better off storing every individual item in seperate columns because it will help you organise the data and allow for fast retrieval. Like you said using other ways of storage (arrays, etc...) would mean longer search time.